# pandas read_csv not working when running via cron on Mac OS

Tags: python, pandas, csv, cron, oserror

I have a python script that is being run by `cron`.  The script imports the pandas module and uses `read_csv` to load a csv to a data frame and then later saves it to another csv.  'apath' is the absolute path to the file:

```
statedata_raw=pd.read_csv(apath+'statedata.csv')
statedata_raw.to_csv(apath+'state_data.csv',index=False)
```

The permissions on the csv file are set correctly `-rwxr-xr-x`

when I run it in the command line, everything works fine.  When I run it via cron I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/maderman/wdtest.py", line 21, in <module>
    statedata_raw=pd.read_csv(apath+'statedata.csv')
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 678, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
OSError: Initializing from file failed
```

I verified that pandas itself is loading and that the `to_csv` is working by replacing the `read_csv`.  When I replaced the `read_csv` with the following code to manually create a dataframe, everything worked fine, running in command line and running in cron:

```
cat=['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b']
val=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
columns=['cat','val']
data=[cat,val]
dict={key:value for key,value in zip(columns,data)}
statedata_raw=pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
```

I found another post that suggested passing the argument `engine='python'` to the `read_csv`, but that didn't do anything.

So I know that:

1. cron is running python fine
2. it can import pandas and run a couple of different pandas functions.
3. the file permissions are fine

The issue seems to be specifically related to the `read_csv` commmand.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I have done some more research and ruled out a few things.  read_csv *does* work, but only when it opens a file that created via cron itself.  I suspect there is some kind of esoteric permissions issue, but haven't figured it out yet.  I have reframed the question in a more specific manner here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framing on this question was wrong and it boiled down to a permissions issue.  A better question was posted and answered here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/62353610](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353610)